# Bootstrap : increase height of 2 parallel divs in a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to  increase height of 2 divs that are  parellel to each other , for example  left  column has less content and right has more content but what i want both should have equal height as left one has a background :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="background:red;">
      <p>Div with less content </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" >
      <p>Div with more content  that  without background </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

need your help with this i am using bootstrap 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row flex">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="background:red;">
      <p>Div with less content </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" >
      <p>Div with more content  that  without background Div with more content  that  without background  Div with more content  that  without background  Div with more content  that  without background  Div with more content  that  without background Div with more content  that  without background </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex{display:flex}
```

Comment: Note that IE is not supporting flexboxes. (http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)

Comment: it works but is there any way to do it  like using bg image etc